# Combinatorics: Picking n marbles from 3 different groups of marbles.

Tags: combinatorics

i'm having a bit of difficulty with a combinatorics problem and i'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction. so here we go.

> In how many ways can one pick n marbles from 3n marbles consisting of n indistinguishable white marbles, n indistinguishable black marbles and n distinguishable colored marbles. your solution should contain a precise explanation.

so i have 3 lines of thought about this:

Attempt 1: we have 3n marbles which can be broken into two groups. Distinguishable vs indistinguishable marbles. considering the indistinguishable marbles i considered them to be a single group of 2n marbles of which i want to choose k from. thus
${2n}\choose{k} $ white and black marbles are able to be chosen at once, i want to choose with out repetition as the marbles are not being replaced and i believe the order doesn't matter in this instance.

next i consider the possible combinations of coloured marbles. since they're all distinguishible my first thought is to consider them to be integer solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n = n-k$$
since each coloured ball is distinguishable i thought of them as single variables, using dots and dividers logic that gives me a total of $$2n-k-1 \choose n-1$$ possible solutions to the above. for a total of
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {{2n}\choose{k}}{2n-k-1 \choose n-1}$$ solutions.

the fault i think with this logic though is that the integer solutions fail as for example we could have n-k $x_1$'s (where $x_1$ represent some colored ball) but in that case those marbles would be indistinguishable from each other, contradicting the idea that they are distinguishable

ok attempt 2:
running with the same line of reasoning above, (picking k balls from a group of 2n first and then dealing with the individual's), this time i'm considering them to be an unordered selection and again with out repetition so that gives me 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {{2n}\choose{k}}{n\choose n-k}$$ solutions.

but this seems wrong to me for some reason and im unable to put my finger on why.

so, third attempt: this is my current line of thinking and i'm considering using generating functions in order to try and explicitly derive a particular formula.
for example, the n distinct marble, i could label $D_i(x)=(1+x)$ and then multiply then together, this would give me $D(x)=(1+x)^n$ and thus at most n distinct marbles.. once figuring out a similar generator for the black and white marbles i would just locate the co-efficient of x^n for the solution.

thoughts? where am i going wrong?
many thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it.

Your task is to take a number, $k$ (ranging from $0$ to $n$), selected from the $n$ *distinct* coloured marbles, and take a number $r$ (ranging from $0$ to $n-k$) of the *nondistinct* white marbles, and however many *nondistinct* black marbles are needed.   Count the *distinct* ways to do this.

$\phantom{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(n-k+1)}$

---

PS: you should know $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom nk=2^n$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\binom nk=n2^{n-1}$